# How to implement the overlay/popup in Whatsapp or Google+?

Tags: android, dialog, material-design

Before going deeper, here is the screenshot of the popup:

[image]
[image]

Are these dialog? FragmentDialog? Or any fancy stuff?

Please guide me to an awesome tutorial about this, thanks!

Comment: "Are these dialog? FragmentDialog? Or any fancy stuff?" -- use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and try to find out. Nobody else, besides the developers of those apps, has any way to know.

Comment: Thanks for the great tool. However, I am not seeing useful information from it. All the classes that are shown, are very low level. For example, FloatingActionButton is extracted as ImageView, while a "real plain Dialog", is just some FrameLayout + TextView.

Comment: There are three possibilities for what any UI structure like you show could be: ordinary views, a dialog, or a dialog-themed activity. **`uiautomatorviewer`** distinguishes between ordinary views and the others, in that it would show you all the views, not just the ones in the popup. There's probably enough information somewhere in **`adb shell dumpsys`** to distinguish the dialog vs. dialog-themed activity scenarios, as the task records will change in the latter but not in the former.